# Factory reset did not remove malware problem on my ZTE zmax blade. What do I do at this point?

Tags: factory-reset, malware

Surveillanceware or a worm of some sort has highjacked my Android and Facebook and email accounts. I'm unable to scan with my premium plus lookout account because the virus has disabled lookout and doesn't allow me to enable it. The Facebook app is uninstallable which I believe to be one of the infected apps. My phone didn't come with Facebook preinstalled before but now it's showing as a system file. I've factory reset and I still have issues. I'm being prompted to reset my password on my Gmail n Facebook sign in page when I know I just reset it and I'm typing it correctly. My photos have vanished. Please someone help me. How do I bring my Android back to health if my antivirus app can't even b enabled. When looking at my apps list I notice apps that I didn't even install and I can't remove them . I started in safe mode and proceeded to uninstall Facebook however Facebook wasn't on the list but when I go to running apps Facebook is there n shows it's running. Help me please, anybody?

Comment: Factory reset has wiped your files, includng your images. as it stands,a reflash or new phone might be your only options, particularly if AV isnt being allowed to work.